# Spring batch application integration with spring batch admin

Tags: spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I developed one spring batch application which is deployed as executable jar using batch/shell script. It works fine.

Now recently I read about spring batch admin application release. As per their doc, they say you have to point to job-context.xml and that will allow to manage spring batch app to be started,restarted and stopped from admin app. Now my question is do I have to keep my job-context.xml outside the jar or what are the exact steps, i am confused about this configuration.
Any insight on this is very useful and by the way I am using spring batch 2.1.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The Spring Batch admin application is a good reference implementation and is highly customizable. All interface implementations may be replaced via Spring DI using your own classes. UI is also template driven(FreeMarker I think) and therefore may be customized to display relevant information, change skin etc.

I had a similar need like yours - need admin functionality included in an app built as jar. I did not quite like the fact that I had to package my jobs as a .war file. Instead I extracted relevant configurations from Spring Batch Admin source and created a deployment that works off file system and runs on embedded Jetty server.

See screen shots here : https://github.com/regunathb/Trooper/wiki/Trooper-Batch-Web-Console

Source, configurations etc are available here : https://github.com/regunathb/Trooper/tree/master/batch-core . This project actually creates a .jar and not .war

Answer (score 1):

If your application has custom classes and is deployed as a runnable jar and not contained within the spring batch admin, you cannot start jobs. You can only view the status of jobs and "kill" their status in the database.

If you look at http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch-admin/reference/reference.xhtml at the end of the Configuration Upload section it states

> You can see a new entry in the job registry ("test-job") which is
>   launchable in-process because the application has a reference to the
>   Job. (*Jobs which are not launchable were executed out of process, but
>   used the same database for its JobRepository, so they show up with
>   their executions in the UI.*)

If your jobs are strictly configurable jobs, as-in you use only XML to define them and do not need to do any customized item readers/processors/writers or other custom classes, then you can upload the job XML and it will be runnable from within the admin site. If you have custom classes then, from my experience, you will have to have the spring batch application deployed within your web application and then upload an XML that contains the jobs you want to run separately.

I personally just used the Admin tool to view job status and provide me with statistics through some custom pages. I left the scheduler to run the jobs and I didn't want those with access to the admin site to kick off a job when they knew nothing about it. Basically, used it to give the users a warm fuzzy without allowing them to muck it up. (leave it to a user to find an edge case you didn't account for)